# Faster query in selecting unique data from duplicate data

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, min

I have a table named attendance with a structure of this:

```
att_id               employee_id               time               status
  1                  101-000001         2019-09-09 08:00:00         1
  2                  101-000001         2019-09-09 17:00:00         2
  3                  101-000001         2019-09-10 08:00:00         1
  4                  101-000001         2019-09-10 08:00:01         1
  5                  101-000001         2019-09-10 17:00:00         2
  6                  101-000001         2019-09-10 17:00:00         2
```

Now i want to get only the unique values with a condition where `employee_id = 000001`.
The output that i want is this:

```
att_id               employee_id               time               status
      1                  101-000001         2019-09-09 08:00:00         1
      2                  101-000001         2019-09-09 17:00:00         2
      3                  101-000001         2019-09-10 08:00:00         1
      5                  101-000001         2019-09-10 17:00:00         2
```

Here is what i did but returns the duplicate data's. :

```
SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE employee_id = "101-000001" AND att_id IN
(SELECT MIN(att_id) FROM tbl_attendance GROUP BY time)
```

Can anyone also suggest me for a solution that is more optimized ?

Comment: What about if you change your grouping in the sub-query. Something like this `(SELECT MIN(att_id) FROM tbl_attendance GROUP BY date(time),status)` maybe?

Comment: @tcadidot0 i'll try it

Comment: @tcadidot0 it gives me no data return

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM attendance 
   WHERE employee_id = "101-000001" 
GROUP BY employee_id,SUBSTRING(time,1,10),status
```

Comment: hello, can you explain or elaborate your answer ?. It give me the correct data but i want some explanation for this

Comment: you just want (status = 1 and status = 2) in one day,att_id = 4 and att_id = 5 the data time is different，group by only time att_id = 4 and att_id = 5 will get.so subtring(time,1,10) date only.